# Change color of JS Variable in Sublime 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I'm looking for the possibility of changing the color of a JavaScript variables in Sublime 3, because at the moment they got the same color like JQuery function calls and other stuff. I'm not looking for a theme. 
I tried a lot in the theme file (`Monokai Bright (SL).tmTheme`) I actual using, but I don't find the right name and scope for variables.

Thought it was:

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Variable</string>

  <key>scope</key>
  <string>variable</string>

  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
  <key>foreground</key>
      <string>#000000</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

But that wasn't the right one. I searched a lot and hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default JavaScript syntax that comes with Sublime doesn't have any rules for highlighting variables. However, the [`JavaScriptNext - ES6 Syntax`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScriptNext%20-%20ES6%20Syntax) package, available through Package Control, does have variable highlighting. It is scoped as `variable.other.readwrite.js`, but in [my theme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) I just use the selector `variable.other`. However, there are other types besides `readwrite`, so I also have different colors for `variable.other.property`, `variable.other.object`, `variable.other.class`, and `variable.other.constant`.

Take a look through the `.tmLanguage` file to see what scopes are available. Another tool I've found to be extremely useful when theming is [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways), which displays the current scope in the bottom bar.

Comment: That kind of worked for me, but with ES6 Syntax it although changed the color of "$" from JQuery to the same color like support functions. How can I change only the color from the "$"? 
I searched with ScopeAlways and tried "meta.function-call.static.with-arguments.js" and "entity.name.function.js", but nothing changed.